# Angular library module inject same service instance of abstract class

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building a library and sample app with Angular 11. I wish to allow the consuming app to inject an implementation of a base class into the library. I have default logic defined in the library. I am defining a provider in the consuming app as thus:

```
// app.module.ts in the root application
providers: [
  {
    provide: 'MyServiceBase',
    useClass: DefaultMyService
  }
]
```

I am defining the base class in the Library:

```
export abstract class MyServiceBase{
   abstract myFunction();
}
```

I define the default logic in the library:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DefaultMyService extends MyServiceBase {
...
}
```

I am injecting the service into a component in the library and a component into the specific class:

```
constructor(@Inject('MyServiceBase') private myService: MyServiceBase) {
...
}
```

The problem I am encountering is that the instance of DefaultMyService being injected into the consuming app is different than the library. When I debug the application, the code being used from the consuming app refrences javascript exported by the library, where as the code being used from the library is actually typescript.

Is there away to inject the same instance into the library and consuming app?

Comment: May be `providedIn: 'root'` would help?

Comment: The class DefaultMyService already had `providedIn: 'root'`.  From my understanding, the instance of DefaultMyService that is used in the app and library should be the same. I don't know why they are different.

Comment: What do you mean "actually typescript"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was overlooking how the service in my library was initialized. It shoudln't have had the Inject token, it was not dependency injected. It was being passed an instance of the MyServiceBase class by the initializing class. The class that was initializing that object was using dependency injection and it was not using the token. I changed that to use the token and it worked.

Edit -

In my case I wanted a component to have its own instance of a class (myNonDepInjectObj below) because there was state that I wanted to keep separate from multiple instances of the component on my page. I however wanted to use a service that was depdency injected in that object. For example here is the correct code that used the token:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject('MyBaseService') myService: MyBaseService) {
    const myNonDepInjectedObj = new MyObj(myService);
  }
}
```

then the correct code for obj class definition:

```
export class MyObj {
  constructor(myService: MyBaseService){
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code which we can refer ?

Comment: I added a little code to clarify. I don't know if it helps.

Comment: You don't need a dummy class ("MyObj"), you can just inject it manually: first inject `Injector` and do `const myNonDepInjectedObj = injector.get(myService);`